# Working with Jquery Context Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu

In my MVC 4 application I am working on ContextMenus with jquery and quite a bit achieved that as well but currently I have been facing issues.

One of my view with  the use of contextmenu looks like this:
[image]

I need to add some menus(namely Move,Delete,Details) on the right click against each of the element(ex:First Document,Doc1 etc) for which my corresponding razor source is:

```
 <div class="row">
   @foreach (var item in Model)
     {
        <div id="dc-row-@item.Id" class="col-sm-3 ">
        <a class="mylinks">@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Name, new { @class = "thumbnail" })</a>

   <ul id="contextmenu1" class="jqcontextmenu">
     <li><a href="#">Item 1a</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Item 2a</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Item 3a</a>
       <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.1a</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.2a</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.3a</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>
}
```

and the script to achieve this is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('a.mylinks').addcontextmenu('contextmenu1') 
})
```

also I have included a jscontextmenu js file to get it working.

But here my problem is that with this I am able to achieve the right click only for the first element only.I feel that with my document ready function the id for contextmenu1 will be applied to the first element only and in order to assign that against all of the names in the list I need to create some dynamic ids for the **ul** and then use it in my script .

I tried with some of the possibities using a counter and incrementing it and then assigning the class to the script function but that didnt work.
So can anyone suggest the way of achieving this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `ul` with id `contextmenu1` is generated for each link (via `@foreach`) which is not valid, as the id should be unique. Try to put it out of `@foreach`.

Comment: Get rid of the id for the `ul`, and attach the contextmenu like this: `$('a.mylinks').addcontextmenu($('a.mylinks').next('.jqcontextmenu'));`

Comment: @ROX - I think with this I will not be able to assign the right click menus against each of the element. Also, on right click I need to send the Id for that element to the controller.So, can you please confirm?

Comment: @MelanciaUK, As per your comment, I removed the id from the ul and added your suggestion in my script removing the earlier one.But now  on right click the menu options are not getting listed.

Comment: It's hard to guess without seeing an example with running code to debug.

Comment: I don't know how exactly you're doing this, but using the selector as I suggested, it seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/nc5sy8uw/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate unique id for each contextmenu:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <a class="mylinks">@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Name, new { @class = "thumbnail" })</a>

    <ul id="contextmenu-@item.Id" class="jqcontextmenu">
        <li><a href="#">Item 1a</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2a</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3a</a></li>
    </ul>
}
```

And in your js code:

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('a.mylinks').each(function () {
        var id = jQuery(this).next('.jqcontextmenu').attr('id');
        jQuery(this).addcontextmenu(id);
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/13tkmfft/).

Comment: I see your fiddle working great and that is all I want but still after all this it is not working.I have been using jqcontextmenu.css and jqcontextmenu.js as src for this .Please guide me what else do I need to do..On right click the default MS links are visible.

Comment: Ya ..its there..Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined .

Comment: @Saroj your `<a>` element and `<ul>` should be next to each other (like in my example). Or try this: `var id = jQuery(this).closest('.row').find('.jqcontextmenu').attr('id');`

Answer (score 1):

It’s time to make the things realistic, it’s time to add some jQuery. try this one!!

```
 <br>
$(document).bind(“contextmenu”, function (e) {<br>
    e.preventDefault();                 // To prevent the default context menu.<br>
    $(“#cntnr”).css(“left”, e.pageX);   // For updating the menu position.<br>
    $(“#cntnr”).css(“top”, e.pageY);    // <br>
    $(“#cntnr”).fadeIn(500, startFocusOut()); //  For bringing the context menu in picture.<br>
});<br>
function startFocusOut() {<br>
    $(document).on(“click”, function () {   <br>
        $(“#cntnr”).hide(500);              // To hide the context menu<br>
        $(document).off(“click”);           <br>
    });<br>
}<br>
$(“#items > li”).click(function () {<br>
    $(“#op”).text(“You have selected “ + $(this).text());  // Performing the selected function.<br>
});<br><br>
```

The above code is very simple.  First we are binding context menu listener to document so that we can handle it. `startFocusOut()` function is used for monitoring the focus lost or to monitor the off menu click. If that click is happened then context menu will be hidden. Click listener on list item is used to perform the selected operation

Answer (score 1):

Probably, something like this should work?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $('a.mylinks li')[0].addcontextmenu('contextmenu1') 
 })
```